# How to hide select2 with options jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have select form with options, for search by keywords. I'm using **select2 lib**.
But my **select form** is created dynamically, and I want to hide and show some select form depending on user's choice.
Now the problem is that, if I choose something from the list:

[image]

For ex **Production plant**, it will appear new **select form** in which I have options. (it's working good)

If I again go to **Production resources** and choose another type:

[image]

Now I chose **Production segment** and prev  **select form** is hidden, but in case if I want to go back to the **Production plant**, it will not appear:

[image]

My code:

```
$("#productionResources").change(function () {
    var prodRes = $("#productionResources :selected").html();
   $("#selectedProdRes").html(prodRes);
    var id = $(this).val();
    if (id != "") {
        $('#' + id).select2().next().show();
    } 
    idChanging(id);

});

function idChanging(id) {
    $("#productionResources").change(function () {
        $('#' + id).select2().next().hide();
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="display-in-row">
        <label>Production resources</label><br>
        <select class="form-control" id="productionResources">
            <option selected></option>
            <option value="productionPlant">Production plant</option>
            <option value="productionSegment">Production segment</option>
            <option value="valueStream">Value stream</option>
            <option value="workCenterGroup">Work center group</option>
            <option value="workCenter">Work center</option>
            <option value="station">Station"</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="display-in-row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label id="selectedProdRes"></label><br>
            <select asp-for="ProductionPlantId" asp-items="Model.ProductionPlant" class="form-control content" id="productionPlant"></select>
            <select asp-for="ProductionSegmentId" asp-items="Model.ProductionSegment" class="form-control content" id="productionSegment"></select>
            <select asp-for="ValueStreamId" asp-items="Model.ValueStream" class="form-control content" id="valueStream"></select>
            <select asp-for="WorkCenterGroupId" asp-items="Model.WorkCenterGroup" class="form-control content" id="workCenterGroup"></select>
            <select asp-for="WorkCenterId" asp-items="Model.WorkCenter" class="form-control content" id="workCenter"></select>
            <select asp-for="StationId" asp-items="Model.Station" class="form-control content" id="station"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please include your HTML codes

Comment: @Franz was edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your function `idChanging()`:

As soon as you change the 1st select, the event of `idChanging()` is set and remains. So everytime you select `#productionResources`, all the events defined by `idChanging()` will get triggered, so all the previously selected selects will be hidden.

The following should work:

I add a class `secondary-select` to all the secondary selects to facilitate, but this is not required:

```html
<div class="display-in-row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <label id="selectedProdRes"></label><br>
            <select asp-for="ProductionPlantId" asp-items="Model.ProductionPlant" class="form-control content secondary-select" id="productionPlant"></select>
            <select asp-for="ProductionSegmentId" asp-items="Model.ProductionSegment" class="form-control content secondary-select" id="productionSegment"></select>
            <select asp-for="ValueStreamId" asp-items="Model.ValueStream" class="form-control content secondary-select" id="valueStream"></select>
            <select asp-for="WorkCenterGroupId" asp-items="Model.WorkCenterGroup" class="form-control content secondary-select" id="workCenterGroup"></select>
            <select asp-for="WorkCenterId" asp-items="Model.WorkCenter" class="form-control content secondary-select" id="workCenter"></select>
            <select asp-for="StationId" asp-items="Model.Station" class="form-control content secondary-select" id="station"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
$("#productionResources").change(function () {
    // Define title
    var prodRes = $("#productionResources :selected").html();
    $("#selectedProdRes").html(prodRes);
    // Make sure none of the 2nd select is visible
    $('.secondary-select').select2().next().hide();
    // Display the select according to the ID
    var id = $(this).val();
    if (id !== '') {
        $('#' + id).select2().next().show();
    } 
});
```

Comment: In this case, when i choose something, all hiden tabs are showing

Comment: @Andrew I just corrected my answer, it should work now

Comment: Thank you, u are save my life :)